# Use a FaceBook FadeIn Effect for new entries to my Datalist

Tags: jquery, datalist, lazy-loading

Ok, I'm using a DataList to display content, I load them based on DateSubmitted, so most recent first.

My DataList is in an updatePanel and I allow users to submit content, then I simply rebind the Datalist and it displays the new content.   What I would like to do though, is apply some kind of LazyLoading or Facebook FadeIn effect, only for the newly submitted content so that it really stands out to the user that it was added.  Not really quite sure how to start doing this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

get jQuery - http://jquery.com/ -  and look into using a highlight effect.

You can use:

```
$("#your_id").effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
```

You would need to include:

```
effects.core.js
effects.highlight.js
```

Comment: I was hoping for a little more detail.  Is there a functioning example of this anywhere, I certainly haven't been able to find one.